# Python search dictionary key in string with priority

Tags: python, search, dictionary

Hi!

I have a string: `697733304440804980633599594374136`. And I have a dictionary: `{'69773330': 'something', '697733304': 'something'}`.

All I need to do is to make my code to search a key `697733304` first and only then make search for `69773330` when I do:

```
print datastring
for key in my_dictionary.keys():
    if key in datastring:
        print key
```

Example output:

```
697733304440804980633599594374136
697733304
69773330
```

Help me pls with that ;)

I guess it's obvious solution but now I can't see it.

Comment: "search a key 69773330 first and only then make search for 69773330" Those are the same numbers? Typo?

Comment: Thank you. It was a mistake. I just edited the post.

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand what you're trying to do?

Comment: @NRKirby I think he's trying to iterate through the dictionary in a specific order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sort the keys before comparing to the string. Also, do not use `string` as a namespace, it's a shadow name of python's `string` module.

Also, remember that the order of dictionary keys is not preserved, and since your keys are in string (*NOT* number), you should sort them without **reserve**.

#### edit:

As @ PadraicCunningham has pointed out, we can even omit the .keys / .iterkeys as it defaults to keys when `sort` or in a `for/loop` already.

```
>>> d = {'69773330': 'something', '697733304': 'something'}
>>> s = '697733304440804980633599594374136'
>>> for key in sorted(d):
...   if key in s:
...     print key
...
69773330
697733304
```

Comment: I used string only here on stackoverflow :)

Comment: @AlexeySlaykovsky, as long as you know it :) I do need to point it out though for others. It will be great if you can edit it, too

Comment: You can just call sorted on d `sorted(d)`.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, very True. Now edited, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So I ran your code and got this as the output:

697733304440804980633599594374136

69773330

697733304

So the only difference is you want the order reversed?

If so:

```
for key in reverse(my_dictionary.keys()):
```

If you want them to always come in that order regardless of how they are entered, you can do:

```
for key in sorted(my_dictionary.keys()):
```

Comment: why reverse? `'69773330' < '697733304' == True `

Comment: Good point, updated.

Comment: Your first attempt happened only because the order of keys are not preserved...

Answer (score 1):

As I said there's obvious answer :)

```
for key in sorted(di.keys(), reverse=True):
    if key in new_key:
        print key
```

Thank God for stackoverflow :)